# How to configure the output to be a virtual audio cable when using ASIO in Adobe Audition?

Tags: adobe-audition, asio

When I use MME in Adobe Audition, I have the option to configure the output to be a virtual audio cable:

[image]

However, when I switch to ASIO, I don't see where I can configure the output to be the virtual audio cable:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to configure the output to be a virtual audio cable when using ASIO in Adobe Audition?

My setup is as follows: I have an Audio-Technica AT2035 microphone connected to a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 USB Audio interface, which is connected to my computer (Microsoft Windows 7). I use Adobe Audition 11.1.1.3 to enhance my microphone audio quality in real time: the input of Adobe Audition should be Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 USB Audio interface, and the output should be a virtual audio cable that I can route to Skype/Dragon NaturallySpeaking/any other programs where I need to use the microphone.

Comment: https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/45785/24007

Comment: @Timinycricket Thanks, that's quite a limitation! Do you have any idea regarding: [How can one achieve a decent latency when using Adobe Audition on Microsoft Windows to enhance one's microphone audio quality in real time?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/45792/6753)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Can you use ASIO input and a different output?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/a/45793/6753), the solution on the Microsoft Windows is to use ASIO4ALL](http://www.asio4all.org/) to be able to configure the audio output to be different from the audio input.

For example, in the following screenshot, ASIO4ALL is configured to use the Focusrite USB as input, and the Virtual Audio Cable as output:

[image]